# How to set up the correct blend function?

Tags: opengl, libgdx, mask, scene2d

I would like to achieve the effect like the image shown:

[image]

When the star pass through a mask, part of the star which under the mask is not shown.

I tried to use blend function, but I don't know how to set up the correct blend function.
I followed this example ( https://gist.github.com/mattdesl/6076846 ), but still can't figure out how to achieve the result I want.

Can anyone teach me how to find the blend function to achieve this effect ??

Comment: I don;t fully understand from your image what is it that you are trying to achieve - what is the image and what is the mask?

Comment: Sorry for the poor presentation.

Comment: The star is a sprite. And the mask is a mask image (green), which is drawn with color mask off on the center grid, i.e. glColorMask(false, false, false, true). So the effect will look like: when the star overlaps the center grid, part of the star will hide under background.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that only with the blending function.

One possible solution is to draw only the part of the star that is visible. You just have to draw a smaller quad.

Another solution is to multiply the star texture alpha by the alpha of the gray texture in the fragment shader (so you need to bind both textured when drawing the star). But that only works if the gray part of the screen is a whole texture and not made of several tiles. I would choose the first solution.

Third solution, you draw the background again on top of the star to hide it.

In first two cases, you only need the usual alpha blending function. To draw the background you can just disable the blending.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to opengl, u said I can't do that only with the blending function......does it mean I'm using the wrong way to draw mask ?? Moreover, thx for your answer.